# Selecting grouped max and min in a Epplus worksheet with Linq

Tags: c#, linq, epplus

I have an Epplus Excel Worksheet that looks like this.

[image]

I want to group by the Group column (in column A), and then select the max and the min.  Something in my `group by` clause isn't quite right and I'm getting an error:  `Cannot apply indexing with [] to ExcelRangeBase`.

```
var maxMinGrouped = from cells in _dataSheet.Cells["A:H"]
                    group cells by cells["A:A"].Value into g //pull "Group" column into group
                    select new
                    {
                        Group = cells["A:A"].Value,
                        MaxDailyIndex = g.Max(c => c.Value),
                        MinDailyIndex = g.Min(c => c.Value)
                    };
```

The SQL I'm trying to achieve.

```
SELECT Group
    ,MAX(Col_E) AS MaxDailyIndex
    ,MIN(Col_E) AS MinDailyIndex
FROM Worksheet
GROUP BY Group
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that the cells collection is a 2x2 matrix so you will need to group cells into rows before you can group into groups of row.  I am way rusty on the query notation of linq but here is how to do it using the dot notation:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Grouped_Row_Test()
{
    //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30466257/selecting-grouped-max-and-min-in-a-epplus-worksheet-with-linq

    var existingFile = new FileInfo(@"c:\temp\Grouped.xlsx");
    using (var pck = new ExcelPackage(existingFile))
    {
        var _dataSheet = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.First();

        //Group cells by row
        var rowcellgroups = _dataSheet
            .Cells["A:H"]
            .GroupBy(c => c.Start.Row);

        //Now group rows the column A; Skip the first row since it has the header
        var groups = rowcellgroups
            .Skip(1)
            .GroupBy(rcg => rcg.First().Value);

        //Reproject the groups for the min/max values; Column E = 5
        var maxMinGrouped = groups
            .Select(g => new
            {
                Group = g.Key,
                MaxDailyIndex = g.Select(o => o.First(rc => rc.Start.Column == 5)).Max(rc => rc.Value),
                MinDailyIndex = g.Select(o => o.First(rc => rc.Start.Column == 5)).Min(rc => rc.Value)
            });

        maxMinGrouped
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(mmg => Console.WriteLine("{{Group: \"{0}\", Min={1}, Max={2}}}", mmg.Group, mmg.MinDailyIndex, mmg.MaxDailyIndex));
    }
}
```

Which gives this in the console after I threw in some random data to your excel table:

```
{Group: "3", Min=0, Max=88}
{Group: "4", Min=6, Max=99}
```

Comment: Is there a way to group by the second column?

Comment: @Cenk Sounds like you want to do a standard `GroupBy` via LINQ using multiple values, e.g. `rowcellgroups.Skip(1).Select(rcg => rcg.ToList()).GroupBy(rcg => new { a = rcg[0].Value, b = rcg[1].Value });` but that is a total guess.  Might want to post a new question if that does not help.

Comment: I asked this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75830564/how-to-read-excel-grouping-by-a-specific-column-in-epplus