# EPPlus Group By Multiple Coulmns

Tags: excel, group-by, epplus

I have an Excel file where I want to group the columns based on multiple columns in C#. I am using EPPlus and have followed this link ([Selecting grouped max and min in a Epplus worksheet with Linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30466257/selecting-grouped-max-and-min-in-a-epplus-worksheet-with-linq)), but it shows only the group by based on one column. I am stuck on extending it to group by multiple coulmns, let's say here Group and Date (Column A and Column B).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the following worked for me where I have grouped by based on first three columns of the Excel file:

```
var rowcellgroups = skus.Cells["A:G"].GroupBy(c => c.Start.Row);
var group = rowcellgroups.Skip(2).GroupBy(x => new { FirstKey = x.ElementAt(0).Value, SecondKey = x.ElementAt(1).Value, ThirdKey = x.ElementAt(2).Value }); //starts with 0
```